# GAE: 404 error on creating a new script

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with Python environment.

I have my main code in the main.py file. I want to create a new .py file for a different page.
I created the .py file, added the path to the yaml file. But I still get a '404 Error, resource not found'.

Here is my yaml file

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /hello
  script: hello.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

When the user goes to exampleurl.com/hello I want the hello.py file to be executed.

Here's the current content of hello.py

```
import webapp2

class HeyPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      self.response.out.write('Hello, All!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/hello', HeyPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Here is the log:

```
INFO     2014-01-10 06:15:31,150 module.py:617] default: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 154
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should list your handlers from most specific to least specific.  Your handler:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

basically says that `main.app` should handle every url.  Since it is the first in the list, `main.py` will try to handle every request regardless of the handlers that follow it in `app.yaml`.  Change it to:

```
handlers:
- url: /hello
  script: hello.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

And all should work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, GAE matches a URL with the patterns in handlers from top to down. .* matches with any URL and as it is the first pattern in the handlers section, it call main.app instead of your hello.app. You should place .* pattern at the end of the handlers section so that any URL that doesn't match with any of your previously defined URL patterns get handled by main.app.

So, modify your handlers section as:

```
application: myapp 
version: 1 
runtime: python27 
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /hello   
  script: hello.app

- url: .*   
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2   
  version: "2.5.2"
```